# Flash: oldschool (pre FP10) 3D rotation?

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d

What was the oldschool way to create a correctly distorted 3D rotation of a Bitmap before FlashPlayer 10 introduced native support for 3D transformations?

I'm not looking for a library like away3D or so, but for the proper actionscript tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone else could explain in more depth the actual trick (I couldn't find a proper link) but there was a small and very simple class in the Sandy engine that did the trick like a charm:
http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage

Comment: jap - that's what i was looking for :)